# Get Font for textbox with fixed width

Tags: vb.net, textbox, font-size

Having VB textbox control with fixed width. How to measure or set font size of the control for given string length ? The string/text should fit into the textbox completly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to measure a string drawn with a specified font. For example, cycle through several font sizes and pick one that fits best into your textbox width.

Another way, which supposedly works better with non-ASCII characters, is [TextRenderer.MeasureText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3812633/897326).